# Setting an existing dictionary's values to all zeros

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have this dict:

```
dict1 = {"Key1": [[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 8]], "key2": [4, 5]}
```

How can I set all the values to `0`?

Output should be like this:

```
dict1 = {"Key1": [[0,0,0], [0,0,0]], "key2": [0,0]}
```

Comment: Doesn't `dict1 = { "Key1" : [[0,0,0][0,0,0]], "key2" : [0,0] }` work?  Missing [] in your definition of "Key1" value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he'd like to do that programmatically

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Problems with the question aside, we need more information on the contents of the dictionary. Otherwise, all the answers will really only be effective on this toy example.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a recursive function that zeros each element of a list or dictionary that is passed to it:

```
dict1 = { "Key1" :[ [1, 3, 4], [2 , 5 , 8]], "key2" : [4, 5] }

def zero(e):
    if type(e) is list:
        return [zero(v) for v in e]
    elif type(e) is dict:
        return {k : zero(v) for k, v in e.items()}
    return 0

dict1 = zero(dict1)
print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
{'Key1': [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], 'key2': [0, 0]}
```

Note that this generates a **new** dictionary rather than mutating the original one.

Comment: Perhaps with noting that this will generate **new** values rather than mutating (zeroing) the original values.

Comment: @donkopotamus good point, I've added a comment to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the dictionary "in-place" — i.e. without replacing it with a new one —  via a relatively simple recursive function:

```
def zero_values(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            obj[k] = zero_values(v)
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for i, v in enumerate(obj):
            obj[i] = zero_values(v)
        return obj
    else:
        return 0

dict1 = { "Key1" :[ [1, 3, 4], [2 , 5 , 8] ], "key2" : [4, 5] }
zero_values(dict1)
print(dict1)  # -> {'Key1': [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], 'key2': [0, 0]}
```

Comment: Was just going to add similar code to my answer but I guess I don't need to bother...

Comment: @Nick: Guess not…although it's unclear whether the OP really cares one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

you can mutate your `dict1` values so that the most inner lists to have only `0` as elements:

```
def change_to_zero(nested_list):
    if isinstance(nested_list[0], list):
        for l in nested_list:
            change_to_zero(l)
    else:
         nested_list[::] = [0] * len(nested_list)

change_to_zero(list(dict1.values()))

print(dict1)
```

**output:**

```
{'Key1': [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], 'key2': [0, 0]}
```

this approach assumes that your `dict` values are lists of different levels of nestedness and the most inner list doesn't have lists as elements,  only integers (for your example)